# Data Not Populating in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to populate my `category` model in my mongo Atlas database with dummy data through a `populdatedb.js` file. In the `category` model, I am self referencing in order to create sub-categories. I am able to populate all the fields in mongo except for the `subcategory` which returns and empty array. Where am I going wrong?

Category Model:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  subheading: { type: String, required: true },
  subcategory: [ this ],
  document: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Document' }],
});

//Export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', CategorySchema);
```

Populdatedb.js

```
var categories = []
function categoryCreate(subheading, sub_cat, doc, cb) {
  categorydetail = {
    subheading: subheading
  }
  
  if (sub_cat != false) categorydetail.subcategory = sub_cat
  if (doc != false) categorydetail.document = doc
  
  var category = new Category(categorydetail);
       
  category.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      cb(err, null)
      return
    }
    console.log('New Category: ' + category);
    categories.push(category)
    cb(null, category)
  }  );
}

function createCategory(cb) {
  async.parallel([
      function(callback) {
        categoryCreate('Category 1', false, documents[0], callback);
      },
      function(callback) {
        categoryCreate('Category 2', categories[0], documents[1], callback);
      }
      ],
      // optional callback
      cb);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking in the future, I figured out the issue.

`async.parallel` needs to be switched to `async.series` so that the first `Category 1` entry can be created which then gives the `Category 2` call of `categories[0]` data to populate.